# to take mean for specific column

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

I have 208 column with each column having value in replicate(so total 104 sample X 2). I want to take mean of all replicates using R loop
Can any one suggest me

```
w x y a b e
5 1 1 2 4 1
6 2 2 5 3 6
7 3 3 8 9 3
8 4 6 9 1 3
```

so for example i have have `w`, `x`, `y`, `a`, `b`, `e` columns
i want to take avaerage of `w` and `x`, `y` and `a` , `b` and `e` 
and Print the average value into another data frame names as `w_x`, `y_a`, `b_e`.

Comment: It is not clear where the replicates are.    Please show a small reproducible example with expected output.  i.e. 10 columns, 5 rows or so for helping others to help you better

Comment: Sorry i have changed the title again.  I need mean

Comment: We don't know how your data looks like or where the replicates are.  Please show a small reproducible example and expected output for that example

Comment: Please edit it in your post

Comment: i have edited the post . Actaully i am not frequent user so don't have much idea about these

Comment: Try `sapply(split.default(df1, (seq_along(df1)-1)%/%2), rowMeans)` and then you change the column names accordingly  or use `sapply(seq(1, ncol(df1), by = 2), function(i) rowMeans(df1[i:(i+1)]))`

Comment: The above code is giving me error

Comment: based on you example, it works for me unless your dataset is different.  If there are `NA` elements, you have to use `sapply(split.default(df1, (seq_along(df1)-1)%/%2), rowMeans, na.rm = TRUE)`

Comment: shall i send you my dataset if you provide maili id

Comment: sorry, you have to show the example here.  If you want to make this reproducible, use `dput(yourexample)` and copy/paste the output in your post

Answer (score 1):

You can also do something like this with `dplyr` + `tidyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

cols = colnames(df)

data.frame(t(df)) %>%
  mutate(ID = rep(paste(cols[1:length(cols)%%2 == TRUE], cols[!1:length(cols)%%2], sep = "_"), each = 2)) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarize_all(mean) %>%
  gather(variable, value, -ID) %>%
  spread(ID, value) %>%
  select(-variable)
```

**Result:**

```
# A tibble: 4 x 3
    b_e   w_x   y_a
* <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1   2.5     3   1.5
2   4.5     4   3.5
3   6.0     5   5.5
4   2.0     6   7.5
```

**Data:**

```
df = read.table(text = "w x y a b e
                 5 1 1 2 4 1
                 6 2 2 5 3 6
                 7 3 3 8 9 3
                 8 4 6 9 1 3", header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mtcarsd <- mtcars[1:6]
```

To access first of two columns use `c(T,F)`

```
first_cols <- mtcarsd[c(T,F)]

sec_cols <- mtcarsd[c(F,T)]

fs <- first_cols+sec_cols
```

Use sapply function to find mean of needed column

```
sapply(fs, mean)
```

Comment: This is giving me "NA" in all my 208 columns

Answer (score 0):

Here is a detailed example using a loop.

```
df <- data.frame(w = c(5, 6, 7, 8),
                 x = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
                 y = c(1, 2, 3, 6),
                 a = c(2, 5, 8, 9),
                 b = c(4, 3, 9, 1),
                 e = c(1, 6, 3, 3))
str(df)
# index of columns on which we will iterate
vect <- seq_len(ncol(df))[seq_len(ncol(df)) %% 2 != 0]
# Extract data frame columns every two columns
# initialize lists
new.lst <- list() # list of dataframes of two consecutive columns
ave.list <- list() # list of averages
for(i in seq_along(vect)){
        new.lst[[i]] <- df[, seq(from = vect[i], to = (vect[i] + 1))]
        ave.list[[i]] <- rowMeans(new.lst[[i]], na.rm = TRUE)
        names(ave.list)[i] <- paste(colnames(new.lst[[i]])[1],
                                    colnames(new.lst[[i]])[2],
                                    sep = "_") # set the names of columns
}
new.lst # list of dataframes of two consecutive columns - complete
ave.list # list of averages - complete
# final dataframe
df2 <- as.data.frame.list(ave.list)
df2
```